# How to execute a method while closing an Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app in which i want to save the date and time inside storage when the user closes the application. I've searched online and found a method -

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.show();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload').subscribe(() => {
    this.logout();
    this.date = new Date();
    let current_Date = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    this.storage.set("LastCheckedDate", current_Date);
  });


});
```

when i place a debugger here and try to close the window on chrome, the debugger gets activated but it doesn't store any value in the storage and i get a null value. How to get this working? I just want to store a timestamp when user closes the app and retrive it later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic run function before app closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033429/ionic-run-function-before-app-closes)

Comment: Where do you put this event? document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ngOnDestroy()` event of the main app component

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.logout();
    this.date = new Date();
    let current_Date = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    this.storage.set("LastCheckedDate", current_Date);

}
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't seem to work. I have put an alert with the value of "LastCheckedDate". I ran the app and force closed it on an android device but the alert that i got had a "null" value.

Comment: getting the "LastCheckedDate" value from storage will imply a promise , how are you alerting the value, in the promise callback?

Comment: this.storage.get('LastCheckedDate').then((val) => {
               
               alert(val);
      
    });

This is how i'm handling it.

Comment: that means the value hasn't been stored

Comment: try `this.storage.set("LastCheckedDate", current_Date).then(()=>{this.storage.get('LastCheckedDate').then((val) => { alert(val); });});`

Comment: For a test, i stored the value into the storage on a button click and then forced closed the app. I got the alert with saved date and time. This means the exit function isn't getting executed.

Comment: what exit function, where do you call the alert?

Comment: What i want to achieve is, when a user just swipes and closes the app forcefully, a function should trigger at the moment and the time stamp should get saved in the storage. When he logs back in, i want to show an alert with the saved timestamp which is obviously a different page.